# getting error when running resty-mongol in Lua through nginx

Tags: mongodb, nginx, lua, mongodb-query, openresty

1. I am getting error when trying to running resty-mongol in Lua
   through nginx. The err is " attempt to index global 'bit' (a nil
   value)". My environment has

   https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/releases/tag/v0.10.6 -
   build with nginx 1.10.1 version.

> Entry thread aborted: runtime error:
>   ...ules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/object_id.lua:56: attempt to
>   index global 'bit' (a nil value) stack traceback: coroutine 0:
>   ...ules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/object_id.lua:56: in main
>   chunk [C]: in function 'require'
>   ...e/modules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/bson.lua:25: in main
>   chunk [C]: in function 'require'
>   .../modules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/colmt.lua:20: in main
>   chunk [C]: in function 'require'
>   ...e/modules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/dbmt.lua:9: in main
>   chunk [C]: in function 'require'enter code here
>   ...e/modules/lua-resty-mongol/lib/resty/mongol/init.lua:14: in main
>   chunk.

2. And after a reboot i am getting on the line

> mongo:new() [string "mongo:new()"]:1: attempt to call method 'new' (a
>   nil value)

I started getting this error all of a sudden and now it fails
everytime. The faliure is at the load module line within my code -
`require "resty.mongol"` line. what possibly have gone wrong. Has
anybody faced it yet?

Comment: How did you install mongol lib?

Comment: do you reallly use luajit?

Comment: i have configured nginx to configure and build with lua-nginx-module             And then i downloaded ngx_openresty ngx_openresty-1.9.7.2.tar.gz  , extracted and installed it. Mongol is just downloaded  from git and appended the init.lua path to package.path in nginx.

Comment: juggling with this issues for past 4 days

Comment: Getting problem with ffl and bit module loading - when running the lua file directly its able to find the modules. I have checked the path and cpath values.. they are same when running directly and when running through nginx. let me know if you need any more info..